# Re-adding WorldWindowGLJPanel to JFrame causes GL viewport miscalculation

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, worldwind

If I add an instance of WorldWindowGLJPanel to my JFrame then remove it and add it again, the panel's GL viewport gets recalculated to a Rectangle that is much smaller than the available space. The dimension appears to consistently be 116x26. What this means is the frame becomes mostly blank with just a small piece of the WorldWind panel displaying in the bottom left corner of the frame. Resizing the frame appears to reset the viewport but is there a way to reset the viewport programmatically?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.Model;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.avlist.AVKey;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.awt.WorldWindowGLJPanel;

public class WorldWindTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final WorldWindowGLJPanel wwPanel = new WorldWindowGLJPanel();
        Model wwModel = (Model) WorldWind.createConfigurationComponent(AVKey.MODEL_CLASS_NAME);
        wwPanel.setModel(wwModel);
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttons.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Re-add WorldWind panel") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.getContentPane().remove(wwPanel);
                frame.getContentPane().add(wwPanel);
                frame.getContentPane().repaint();
            }
        }));
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(wwPanel);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

4 and half years late to the party, but posting my solution because I couldn't find one when I ran into this issue.

This problem seems to have nothing to do with WorldWindowGLJPanel, I believe it's a problem with any GLJPanel.

When you remove the GLJPanel from its parent, it resets its internal pixel scaling to some sentinel values. That's why it becomes tiny, but continues to (sorta) work.

The following 3 lines of code fixed it for me (I add them to a hierarchy listener and call them when the parent changes, but you can add them to the SSCCE above in the button handler)

```
                wwPanel.initializeBackend(false);
                wwPanel.reshape(0, 0, 0, 0);
                wwPanel.revalidate();
```

initializeBackend tells OpenGL to initialize the backend, if it isn't initialized (Not 100% sure what causes it, but it seems to be tied to moving between parent windows).

Reshape will overwrite those pixel scale sentinel values, and so it'll actually calculate the proper size to display.

Revalidate causes it to recalculate the size of the panel, which I believe kicks off the size calculations now that those sentinel values aren't in the way.

Comment: I actually forget what problem I was working on here. Probably something for some project I'm no longer working on. That said, I really appreciate the response. If I come across this again, I will definitely test it out. Sounds simple, which is great.